# CURL issue on new Server

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl

I am trying to curl the below location;

```
Curl::to('https://serp.webshed.co/')->enableDebug('/uploads/log/logFile.txt')->get();
```

When I load the URL directly in my browser it works fine, when I try curling it from my local dev it works fine. When I try and curl it from my actual system online it times out, the error I get is;

```
*   Trying 46.101.38.201...
* Connected to serp.webshed.co (46.101.38.201) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: It could be that the target server is overloaded or the SSL version

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have now got an additional line in the log - ```Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped``` would that be due to a dns change?